# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special._ufuncs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I already installed scipy on Python3.6:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
pip3 install scipy
```

But, it does not work with this error.:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special._ufuncs'
```

How can I do?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `ufuncs` (aka [Universal Functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html)) is part of the [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) framework. When working with SciPy, it is necessary to install NumPy first as it's a dependency. You are getting this [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError) is likely due to the unavailability of NumPy package.

Before you try anything, list the currently installed packages:

`pip3 list`

If NumPy isn't installed then try installing it:

`pip3 install numpy`

**Edit:**

It seems that you had tried install scipy using ubuntu package installer. That's why your scipy version is 0.17. Sometimes it is possible that some ubuntu packages are outdated. Therefore, it's better to use the official package managers, like [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) in case of Python.

First uninstall the scipy installed by the package manager:

`sudo apt-get purge python3-scipy`

When uninstalled successfully, reinstall it using PyPI:

`pip3 install scipy`

This will install the latest version ([1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/)) from python package index.

If all goes well, you should be able to run your code without any errors.

Comment: I used pip3 list. Numpy 1.15.1 is already installed.
And I attempted
`pip3 install --upgrade scipy`

But, this phrase appears.

**Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/0b/f163da98d3a01b3e0ef1cab8dd2123c34aee2bafbb1c5bffa354cc8a1730/scipy-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scipy) (1.15.1)
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.17.0**

Comment: **Cannot uninstall 'scipy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.**

Comment: It is probably a pip issue. Try reinstalling scipy instead, using `pip3 install --ignore-installed scipy`

Comment: Also your scipy installation is too old, and I see where it is coming from. I'll edit the answer to incorporate the changes.

Comment: The comment about ufuncs is wrong, sorry. The message is about a part of scipy.special package, which also ships several ufuncs.

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't use `sudo pip`. 
Best use a virtualenv, and install everything into it.
What you see is a sign of a broken install, best reinstall from scratch --- or activate a virtualenv.