# modules are throwing errors

Tags: python, error-handling, scipy

I am trying to use the integrate function from scipy 1.6.3 for Gaussian Quadrature however I keep getting this error and I don't understand why. I hover over it and it's all selected properly. I have the correct version of scipy and python too.

This is the error - No module named scipy.special

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from scipy import integrate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PIL import Image
    def gaussian(self):
        def function(x):
          resultinput=self.EquationInput.text()
          finalinput=eval(resultinput)
          return self.finalinput
    lower = self.ScrollLower.value()
    upper = self.ScrollUpper.value()
    self.result=integrate.quadrature(function, lower, upper)
    self.result=str(self.result)
    self.CalcOutput.setText(self.result)
```

Comment: Please, try to isolate the error, add a fully reproducible code and post the complete traceback. Thanks

Comment: Would it be okay to give a link to a pastebin? Don't want to flood this question with a tonne of code

Comment: As minimal code as possible to reproduce the error. You need to isolate it.

Comment: Here is minimal code that produces the same error 'import scipy
from scipy import integrate

    
def gaussian(self):
        function = x**2
        lower = -1
        upper = 1
        result=integrate.quadrature(function, lower, upper)
        print(result)'

Comment: And which line of this snippet is throwing the error? You're not calling `scipy.special` here.

Comment: Thats the thing, i'm not trying to call it at all anywhere. scipy.special isn't called anywhere in my code

Comment: Start another clean session `from scipy import integrate; func = lambda x: x**2; integrate.quadrature(func, -1, 1)` is this throwing errors?

Comment: I have tried a fresh session and am still getting the same 'No module named 'scipy.special' error

Comment: With my one-line code?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said. I'm not sure if it's something I have done or something within an update or scipy?

Comment: Try to reinstall `scipy` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255471/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-scipy-special-ufuncs